# How to find maximum value in the column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code.I will try to read file and find the maximum temperature value(11th column)

```
import pandas as pd

fn = 'Excel.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(fn, header=None)
df1 = df.iloc[:,11:12]
m1 = df.iloc[:,11:12].max()
print (m1)
```

What I got is not want I wanted

```
python n0.py 
11    Value
dtype: object
```

I will show how the 11-th column looks like

```
0      Value
1      18.71
2      20.86
3      18.37
4       12.3
5       5.54
6       3.96
7       8.33
8      12.23
9      11.02
10      4.18
11      7.62
12     15.06
13        20
14     20.39
15     18.26
16     14.54
17      3.81
18      0.93
19      7.74
20     12.42
21      6.59
22      0.12
23      8.32
24     16.82
25     19.46
26      11.8
27      6.25
28      1.96
29     17.13
       ...  
756    15.59
757     6.82
758     7.48
759    14.99
760    17.61
761    19.48
762     16.8
763     9.65
764     1.63
765     9.26
766    16.25
767    24.85
768    14.08
769     0.11
770     6.56
771    12.75
772    21.94
773    20.57
774    17.97
775    12.73
776     6.16
777     9.12
778    19.03
779    17.39
780    14.06
781     1.76
782     8.25
783    17.41
784    20.61
785    20.73
```

From these values 24.85 would be the max and it is on 767 position. I have not worked with pandas lately but this was supposed to be simple job.
Where is my mistake?
Should I use idmax or something else?

Comment: What is the 11th column's name? You can just select the column: `df[df.columns[11]].max()`

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 it gives Value

Comment: The elevenths column has actually the index `10`. So it would be `df[df.columns[10]].max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert column to `numeric` by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

and then need for `12`th column:

```
max = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,11], errors='coerce').max()
```

and for `11`th need `10`, because python counts from `0`:

```
max = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,10], errors='coerce').max()
```

Comment: @jezreal Probably something is wrong,the way I read Excel file.I got Value.